# Possible variant of Lovász: Graphs without 3 vertex-disjoint cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory

Is there a classification, or perhaps some exhaustive description, of graphs without 3 vertex-disjoint cycles,
and/or do you maybe know about some reference for such?

The case of graphs without 2 vertex-disjoint cycles is handled by Lovász' classification,
and I was wondering whether there is also a similar description possible for those without any 3 vertex-disjoint cycles.